# Jquery detect textbox programmatic change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Long story short I am cowboying some code in which a custom framework I am using allows me to insert a script to manipulate the page to do what I want.

I want to fire a function, but only after the textbox I want to use has been populated from the webservice that gets called.

In Jquery/Javascript is there anyway to call a function like the jquery change function, but one that can detect when the textbox has been changed from javascript, and not by the user in the browser.

I currently just have:

```
$("#mytexbox").on('input propertychange paste change',function() {
   doSomething();
});
```

But this does not fire when the original function in locked code sets the value of the textbox.

Note: I can not just overload the original function as most of it is built up from dynamic server side code that I can't mimic in Javascript.

I also want to avoid having to use setTimeout() as this is unreliable and not really a nice solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there is an api you can use other than interval timer. MutationObserver Api doesn't support value changes

Comment: Register global `$.ajaxComplete` handler and check changes from it.

Comment: You could check for keydown, keyup or keypress and see if those events were fired before the element content was changed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a hidden div or input and check the changes on this instead of changes on #mytextbox. Obviously, the user can not change the hidden div, but the script can. You get the trick? ;)

Comment: I don't think you read the question. I only have access to a script file to basically cowboy the original page. I can create a div in js, but I still don't know when the textbox gets populated, to then be able populate the hidden div. 
I can't access the original function to allow it to populate the hidden div, otherwise I would just trigger my function from there instead of when the textbox gets populated.